# Как сделать рестарт активити?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.В приложении есть метод который делает много чего.и после этого надо убить Активити и сново его перезапустить.Пробовал через интент вот так

```
İntent intent  = new Intent(...)
startActivity(..)
finish
```

но оно не работает .
Какие есть методы *"перезагрузки "* `Activity`

Comment: А для каких целей? Может всё решается более простым путем

Comment: @RomanDanilov есть проект в ней логика заложена не правильно а переписывать её не мое дело .моё лишь то чтоб оно хоть как то работало)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для пересоздания активити на API level 11+ можно вызвать метод [`recreate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate()), на меньших API levels это можно сделать вручную:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Итого:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
    recreate();
} else {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: спасибо да помогло )проблема исчерпана )

Comment: интересно а почему метод рекреат убрали

Comment: @elik, Его не убрали, его добавили.

Comment: ааа блин всё)))))вобще прелесть ))))

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mActivity = MainActivity.this;

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restart_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                restartActivity(mActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public static void restartActivity(Activity activity) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            activity.recreate();
        } else {
            activity.finish();
            activity.startActivity(activity.getIntent());
        }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое